# Delete a UITableViewCell on clicking the custom delete button

Tags: objective-c, ios

I Basically have a UITableViewCell Class with a custom Delete Button appearing when swiping a cell using Pan Gesture.

Something like this.
_delBtn is my Delete Button.On clicking that it should delete the TableCell.
Please help me on this

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
  {

   CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self];
   recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, recognizer.view.center.y);
   [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:_baseView];

if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) 
{

    translation.y = 0;
    CGPoint velocity = [recognizer velocityInView:_baseView];
    CGFloat magnitude = sqrtf((velocity.x * velocity.x));
    CGFloat slideMult = magnitude / 1000;
    NSLog(@"magnitude: %f, slideMult: %f", magnitude, slideMult);

    float slideFactor = 0.1 * slideMult;

    velocity.x = velocity.x + 1000;
    velocity.y = 0;

    CGPoint finalPoint = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + (velocity.x * slideFactor),
                                     recognizer.view.center.y + (velocity.y * slideFactor));
    finalPoint.x = MIN(MAX(finalPoint.x, 0), _baseView.bounds.size.width);
    finalPoint.y = MIN(MAX(finalPoint.y, 0), _baseView.frame.size.height);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:slideFactor*2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{

        recognizer.view.center = finalPoint;

    } completion:nil];


    if (finalPoint.x >= 195) 
    {

        _delBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, 60, 60)];
        [_delBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"delBtn3.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_delBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        _delBtn.hidden = NO;
        [_baseView insertSubview:_delBtn atIndex:0];
        _delBtn.alpha = 0;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:slideFactor delay:0.4 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{

            recognizer.view.center = finalPoint;

        } completion:nil];
```

Comment: Remove the datasource for the specified cell and call [tableview deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:.... ]

Answer (score 1):

In your `deleteClicked` method, you will need to have the `UITableView` delete the cell. The cell will need to have a reference to the `UITableView` that contains it as well as knowledge of the row and section it represents in the table.

The `UITableView` parent can be obtained with the `self.superview` property, but it may be safer to store a weak reference in your own custom property, or better yet, a reference to the `UIViewController` class that manages the `UITableView`. This way you can simply create a method in the controller that you can call to delete the cell.

You will also need to create a property to store the `NSIndexPath` that your `UITableViewCell` currently represents in the table, if you don't already have access to this information in some other custom property in the cell class. You will set these properties in the `UITableViewDataSource` method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` when you initially create or deque the `UITableViewCell`.

In your `deleteClicked` method, you can call the method in your `UIViewController`, something like `deleteCellAtIndexPath:`, passing it the `NSIndexPath` of the cell that needs deleting.

In this `deleteCellAtIndexPath:` you will do two things. First, amend the backing data source for your `UITableView` by removing the data object for the cell to be deleted. This is likely some sort of `NSMutableArray`.

After removing the backing data, call the method `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` on the `UITableView`, passing it the `NSIndexPath` as the only object in an `NSArray`. Your cell should then be deleted, animating it as specified with the `UITableViewRowAnimation` parameter. See the [`UITableView` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITableView) for more information regarding these methods.